# using django cities light in template

Tags: python, django

I have installed Django city light. Now I want to populate my city field in registration form with all the cities in django city light. All the documents doesn't provide any guidance on how to do that. My model is :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

i want to populate all the cities in location field and if possible with auto complete functionality.

Comment: And how do you use django-city-light here? You location should be FK to another model. And this model should inherit `AbstractCity` or `AbstractRegion` from django-city-light.

Comment: just downloaded cities light and want integrate it with my location field.

Answer (score 4):

After [installation](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light) and populating the tables by

```
python manage.py cities_light
```

define `city` as a foreign key.

```
from cities_light.models import City

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

To see what the `City` object is like, open a shell session `python manage.py shell` and type

```
from cities_light.models import City
c1 = City.objects.get(id=100)
dir(c1)
```

The most relevant geo information may be

```
c1.name
c1.region
c1.country
c1.latitude
c1.longitude
```